# Spring WebsecurityConfig is calling filter every request

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I need to create a WebSecurityConfig to handle filters. I want that every req pass to the filter except the ones that have "authenticate" at the path. This is what I am trying to do:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.antMatcher("/**").addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(TokenTypeEnum.ACCESS),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        httpSecurity.antMatcher("**/authenticate").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

The problem that in this way, every req becomes open. If I change the order of lines, every req is filtered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the location of `authorizeRequests()`, and put `addFilterBefore` like this:

**WebSecurityConfig**:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

If you are using **jwt**, can implement a rule for unauthenticated users:

**JwtAuthenticatioFilter**:

```java
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        String username = null;
        String authToken = null;
        if (header != null && header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            authToken = header.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX,"");
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("an error occured during getting username from token", e);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.warn("the token is expired and not valid anymore", e);
            } catch(SignatureException e){
                logger.error("Authentication Failed. Username or Password not valid.");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("couldn't find bearer string, will ignore the header");
        }
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            authenticationService.authenticate(req, username, authToken);
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

}
```

**JwtTokenUtil**:

```java
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    public static final long ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 5*60*60;
    public static final String SIGNING_KEY = "stack-overflow";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8713473373534700606L;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(SIGNING_KEY)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(User user) {
        return doGenerateToken(user.getUsername());
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(String subject) {

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(subject);
        claims.put("scopes", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")));

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuer("http://stack.com")
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS*1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SIGNING_KEY)
                .compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (
              username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())
                    && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

}
```

**AuthenticationService**:

```java
@Service(value = "authenticationService")
public class AuthenticationService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public String autenticate(Login login) throws ParseException{
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login.getUsername(), login.getPassword()));
        User user = userService.findByUsername(login.getUsername());
        String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(user);
        return token;
    }

}
```

**AuthToken**:

```java
public class AuthToken {

    private String token;
    private String username;

    public AuthToken(){

    }

    public AuthToken(String token, String username){
        this.token = token;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public AuthToken(String token){
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**Authentication endpoint**:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/generate-token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public AuthToken register(@RequestBody Login login) throws AuthenticationException 
    {
        try {
            String token = authenticationService.autenticate(login);
            return new AuthToken(token, login.getUsername());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

**UserService**:

```java
@Service(value = "userService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService
{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;    

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;


    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        if(user.isPresent() == false){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.get().getUsername(), user.get().getPassword(), true, true, true, true, null);
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<User> i = userRepo.findAll().iterator();
            i.forEachRemaining(block -> {
                User next = i.next();
                list.add(next);
            }
        );
        return list;
    }

    public User findByUsername(String username) throws ParseException {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        return optionalUser.isPresent() ? optionalUser.get() : null;
    }

    public User findById(String id) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepo.findById(id);
        return optionalUser.isPresent() ? optionalUser.get() : null;
    }

}
```

**UserRepository**:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

You can test, using Insomnia:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering but still not working. Every req is passing in the filter.

Comment: ahh, yes, in my application too, but, you can implement a rule inside  your filter to by pass.

Comment: inside your `AuthenticationFilter`, method: `doFilterInternal` implement a logic for this case.

Comment: @RenanGeraldo, it doesn't make sense to implement a filter to execute only sometimes, the concept of a filter is to run every request. You need to adapt our logic to the patern.

Comment: Ok, now I am trying to do that, but when I try to get the url path, I get null every time.

Comment: @RenanGeraldo, I couldn't understand your problem now, why you need the url path? Can you show me the code? Are you using **jwt**? Can you show me the `AuthenticationFilter` code?

Comment: I am trying your approach. There are no reqs passing in the filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot danilo! Going to check soon.